# Ajustar ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou tentando ajustar um layout usando o novo `ConstraintLayout`, más não estou conseguindo, poderiam me dar um help? segue abaixo meu layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.pdibar.pdibarlio.frags.VendaFragment"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edProdutoCarrinho"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/busca"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Selecione o produto..."
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbValorItemCarrinho"
    android:layout_width="180sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="R$ 0,00"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edProdutoCarrinho" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edQntItemCarrinho"
    android:layout_width="80sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:text="1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lbValorItemCarrinho"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edProdutoCarrinho" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btAddItemCarrinho"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Adicionar"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edQntItemCarrinho"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edProdutoCarrinho" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvCarrinho"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_driver"
    android:dividerHeight="1sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btFechaCarrinho"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbValorItemCarrinho" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Itens"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lbQntItensCarrinho"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbQntItensCarrinho"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="0000"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Total"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lbTotalCarrinho"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lbQntItensCarrinho" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbTotalCarrinho"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="R$ 0,00"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lbQntItensCarrinho" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btFechaCarrinho"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:text="Fechar"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Eu quero que o total de itens, o valor total e o botão fechar, fiquem sempre no final e conforme imagem, eles ficam assim, mesmo tendo itens no `listview`, e o `listview` não está aparecendo...

[image: Resultado do layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando  você está usando o ConstraintLayout você define onde quer que seu componente fique linkado, ou seja, qual será a referência de posição pra ele.

Você pode definir usando a caixa lateral de propriedades do Android Studio conforme essa imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso o componente txtTítulo está linkado ao topo da Activity com uma distância entre eles de tamanho 16dp. Você consegue ver na lateral azul onde estão as constraints que definem a posição dele.

Se você posicionar manualmente e depois for nessa varinha mágica em cima da tela ele cria essas definições automaticamente com base no posicionamento que você definiu.

Via código, você pode fazer utilizando as opções em layout_constraint... (aqui são várias e depende do que você irá querer.
O código do textView da imagem está assim:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitulo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/cadastrar_pat"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/viewfinder_laser"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```